# How can I use Python and Selenium to auto login an element that is said to be not visible?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently writing a script and have succeded using selenium and python to open browser and navigate to the login screen on the website I will provide. But when I enter either of these 2 scripts, it doesn't work. It just says login not visible. Can someone tell me how I can do using Pythong and Selenium.

```
# fill in username
username = browser.find_element_by_id('id_username')
username.send_keys(usernameStr)
nextButton = browser.find_element_by_id('next')
nextButton.click()
```

and even used this one I found someone suggested

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://.com/auth/login/
")

action = action_chains.ActionChains(driver)

login = driver.find_element_by_class_name("login-icon")
login.click()

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('custlogin'))

username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')

action.move_to_element(username).perform()

username.send_keys('testeruser')
```

If someone could help me with this issue, I can go proceed on happily. Thank you for anyone that reads this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Off-topic questions such as this one are routinely closed, but if edited to ask an *answerable* question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, I have set it as a question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Locator Strategy* which you have used doesn't identifies the `username` field uniquely. The currect *Locator Strategy* identifies a *hidden field*. To identify the *username* and *password* field uniquely you can use the following lines of code :

```
username = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//fieldset[@class='fieldset_main']//input[@id='id_username']")
password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//fieldset[@class='fieldset_main']//input[@id='id_password']")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly. I have been trying everything but didnt know of this strategy. Will definitely remember it. If possible, is there one more thing you can help with. I am trying to write a code to click the button which I havent had a problem with before but this wasn't doesn't have html. So I am down without a clue. This is the element to the login button.

Comment: <input type="submit" value="login" class="button">